# Problems to read a Synology raid1 disk in Ubuntu

Tags: mount, raid, mdadm, fdisk, nas

I'm trying to recover the data from a disk of a Synology NAS. It was stored in a 2 disk RAID1. One of the disk broke and I didn't replace it. After some months, Synology station broke too, and now I have to try to get info from an ubuntu.

This is the disk:

```
root@luis-Ubuntu:~# fdisk -l /dev/sdb
Disk /dev/sdb: 1,84 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: 003-9VT166
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000ba95f

Device     Boot   Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1           256    4980735    4980480  2,4G fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb2       4980736    9175039    4194304    2G fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb3       9437184 3907015007 3897577824  1,8T  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sdb5       9453280 3907015007 3897561728  1,8T fd Linux raid autodetect
```

I tried to assemble it:

```
root@luis-Ubuntu:~# mdadm --assemble --scan
mdadm: No suitable drives found for /dev/md/2
```

Some problems detected. I examined the partition with mdadm:

```
root@luis-Ubuntu:~# mdadm --examine /dev/sdb5
/dev/sdb5:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : e869adda:dd078e08:11ed8189:7f811d58
           Name : DiskStation:2
  Creation Time : Fri Mar 11 13:30:10 2011
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 3897559680 (1858.50 GiB 1995.55 GB)
     Array Size : 1948779648 (1858.50 GiB 1995.55 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3897559296 (1858.50 GiB 1995.55 GB)
    Data Offset : 2048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=1968 sectors, after=384 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : e0ad9477:9a814591:1445e724:f88423c6

    Update Time : Sun Mar 10 15:44:28 2019
       Checksum : f83390a2 - correct
         Events : 23479526


   Device Role : Active device 32769
   Array State : A. ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

This is the detail scan output:

```
root@luis-Ubuntu:~# mdadm --detail --scan
INACTIVE-ARRAY /dev/md2 metadata=1.2 name=DiskStation:2 UUID=e869adda:dd078e08:11ed8189:7f811d58

And this is the mdstat:
root@luis-Ubuntu:~# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md2 : inactive sdb5[2](S)
      1948779840 blocks super 1.2

unused devices: <none>
```

I'm a very new user in raid configurations, but all of this is what I could get and hope helps you in helping me :)

I think the disc is OK and I'm doing it wrong. How could I open and extract files on it?

**Thank you**

Luis

Comment: I would be asking the company that made it  Synology NAS if that is possible or if they have a forum.

Comment: Yes, I checked a KB they have.
I'll ask in their forums too. Thanks!